# How long is the D&D Starter Set campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, time, lost-mine-of-phandelver, system-introduction

I'm pretty interested in buying the [D&D Starter Set](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_starterset) as a way to get introduced to D&D and being a GM/DM for the first time. Ever since I discovered this RPG Stack, I have read a lot of D&D Q/A out of curiosity and I really wanted to try it out.

I have already played a bit as a player with a group of friends, and I'd like to DM for this group as I'm a bit shy and I know them pretty well so I can anticipate how they will act and can react better to this.

**What I'd like to know is**: Given a party of moderately experienced players (a party of about 4/5 at maximum), and considering the information above, roughly how many hours of play can the starter set campaign be expected to last? (at a minimum, without including side quests/jobs, with fights going well, etc...).

Prior experience with the starter set would be really appreciated.

As a note, I've also asked a second question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142156/can-i-easily-string-dnd-starter-set-campaign-to-another-module) about transitioning from the starter set to another module.

Comment: I do not think this needs closure. All of the answers are exactly what we look for: actual gameplay experience. And there seems to be a consensus.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So this is more of a guess because I played half this module and DM'd it once for another group.

If you really just go for main plot and your group is straight forward, then I think it still would take at  least 30 hours.

When your group likes to roleplay or have some fun combined with some sidequests, then I think this can easily go up 70 hours.

The group I DM'd meets every week and we play about 4-5 hours per session. With all the sidequests we finished after 3 months. This party was completely new to the game and we had some start issues. We also lacked a bit on the roleplay part. At the end most of my players reached level 4.

There are people that DM this module regularly they probably can give you a more precise answer. But for now i hope this helps you.

Comment: When I ran this module (as a new DM with new players), we blew through chapter 1 very quickly, took a 3 hours detour in chapter 2 and took our sweet time with cragmaw castle and beyond. It depends on the group. If they explore every nook and cranny of every map, it'll take a lot longer than 30 hours. Running to the end of every map will probably take close to 20 hours. 30 is a very fair estimate.

Comment: My group fell apart right before the Wave Echo Cave but I'd second this rough time-estimate

Answer (score 10):

### 50 hours over 14 sessions for my group

I've recently just finished being DM for a group going through LMOP. They started with four players and ended with five and went through every location and side-quest mentioned in the book. I also added in some homebrew roleplay opportunities, combat encounters and locations for them to explore, but these only took up about 8-10 hours of the overall time.

My group were very inexperienced though as it was the first time any of use had ever played D&D. The players took a long time and multiple discussions to come to any sort of agreement over what course of action to take. They were also not very focused although this got better towards the end.

It was however a LOT of fun. I don't think there were any moments where we were bored or underwhelmed by the adventure. So we all definitely got a lot of good value (time and entertainment) wise out of the adventure.

Comment: So 40-42 hours without the homebrew part ? Did your players were only new to DnD in particular or to RP in general ?

Comment: Yeah that sounds right. Brand new to TTRPG's, except for one who regularly plays Warhammer. The rest had a mix of experience with video games, card games, other board games etc. So I think for them a big part of the reason why it took so long is because it was a new way of playing games they had no experience in.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot for these precisions. I'm now pretty sure that this will be long enough to be sure that both me and my party would like to continue with another module (maybe Storm King's Thunder as saw in the other questions answers).

Comment: After finishing LMOP, my group is now currently playing Storm King's Thunder. Although they wanted new characters for this campaign, it would definitely be a great transition for you.

Answer (score 3):

My group of **VERY** (read, very) new players is about 85% of the way finished with it and it's taken 7 sessions so far. Some of our sessions were a little shorter than three hours, but thats about 20ish hours so far. This leads me to believe it would be less than 10 sessions maximum and experienced players could probably do it in 6 sessions. LMoP "by the book" is pretty much on rails, there's a natural progression that it leads you to. Of course if your players want to go off the rails, that takes time.

My group also did one of the "side" missions:

> They went to Thundertree to find the location of Cragmaw Castle, instead of searching out a goblin raiding party. The druid there gave them the information, but they never asked where Wave Echo was even though the book seems to suggest the druid would know where it is, therefore skipping Cragmaw entirely.

One final point:

> The last area "Wave Echo Cave", can take a lot of time because its not a linear progression through the dungeon.

Comment: The one they did do, I'm not sure counts as a side mission as it is part of the main story path.

Comment: I would highlight that they **only** did one (minor) one, if that's the case. Or say that they nearly entirely just followed the main story :). That may be more helpful :)

Comment: @Stickyz Your estimation is the shorter here so I'd like more details about your party. Did they roleplayed a bit about actions they did or just saying what there characters do ?

Comment: @Zoma They dont RP much at all, extremely new players that need a decent amount of direction. We also have 5 players every session. However, I think its more of a reflection on the actual module, it can be extremely linear and an experienced group could breeze through it. There are also some...interesting shortcuts that the book seems to lay out. Of course dnd has a way of going off even the tightest of rails. 6, 4 hour sessions (24 hours) could probably finish it if all the...more obvious clues are followed and they move quickly through the last dungeon.

Comment: @Stickyz A more experienced group is no more likely to move quickly through a module. D&D isn't a videogame that you get 'better' at. In fact, experienced players may move slower with caution learned the hard way in previous campaigns.

Comment: @linksassin i think that's 100% correct in most settings, however for LMoP its very on rails and I think anyone that's done any RPG before can see them and follow them. There are also a lot of shortcuts written into the modules (like I've mentioned). Of course if the DM wants to let them hop the rails and do other stuff, that's a different story completely. .

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give an optimistic estimate of 6 sessions, or about 24 hours. I'm basing this on three sessions that I played with a few friends, where we were able to get about halfway through the campaign. I should note that my friends opted to skip all of the side quests. Also, based on my personal experience it will take longer with a larger group. We're currently running Curse of Strahd right now, but with at least five players rather than just two to three. It's moving a lot slower.

Comment: I'm going to leave my answer up for right now, but Xirem seems to have more experience with the module than myself so his estimate is probably better.

Comment: every point of view is good to have as your party skipped all sidequests while Xirems did these ones. And it has pointed to me that I forgot to tell the size of my potential party.

Answer (score 2):

### My group took 27 sessions ~ 75h, but could be done in 40-45h by a faster group

My group consisted of 5 players – 4 new players (one of whom joined a few sessions in) and one moderately experienced one.

This was all played over zoom, which slows things a bit; our sessions ran about 2.5 - 3h of *play* (but more like 4h with catching up, chit-chat, lamenting covid, discussing character choices, etc).

The first few sessions in particular went very slowly as they got used to the mechanics and to roleplaying.

The group are also fairly slow overall:

- they tend to investigate *everything*, which keeps me on my toes, and means I need a lot of random stuff prepped ready for them to find
- they plan combat carefully before they go in. Planning up from is their kind of fun; they synergise well and it's rare for anyone to get KO; but it is slow).

I've kept records of sessions, so I can give you a breakdown:

> - Session 0 – Session 0, introduce characters & goblin attack
>  - Session 1 – fight with redbrands
>  - Session 2-3 – cragmaw cave
>  - Session 4 – Banshee & Wyvern Tor
>  - *Session 5 – journeying encounters, shopping, exposition*
>  - Session 6-8 – Redbrand hideout + a lot of discussion about what to do with the nothic
>  - *Session 9-11 – sidequests related to Levelling up: travelled to Triboar, a feywild encounter to justify the ranger's *Fey Wanderer* subclass; Paladin oath; meeting Big Al from DoIP & claiming his ranch for him (crossover event for the experienced player who was also playing DoIP in another group I DM)*
>  - Session 12 – the well – including a slightly extended investigation of the ruins
>  - *Sesson 13 – Travel encounters, investigating where the castle is*
>  - Session 14-17 – the castle, *including the excellent sidequest https://cros.land/2019/09/quest-the-redemption-of-agatha-the-banshee/, which is well worth running* Didn't get the map.
>  - Session 18-19 – Thundertree. *This encounter is very dangerous; if your players are used to level-appropriate encounters, make sure you telegraph the danger; taking Venomfang head-on will probably be a TPK. My group parlayed but even still just averted a permadeath.*
>  - *Session 20 – travelled to Neverwinter, shopping, seeding of future plotlines*
>  - *Session 21 – ransacked the castle convinced they needed to find the map; essentially off-plot, but it'd re-filled with new monsters in the time they were away*
>  - Session 22-26 – Wave Echo Cave. A lot of time wasted discussing which enemy to betray to which, and repeatedly fighting the flameskull.

So, of those 27 sessions, only 20 were 'on plot' – though some off-plot is to be expected and breaks up the pace – but a more efficient group could probably get through all the content in 15.