# How long is the D&D vs. Rick and Morty adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, time, the-lost-dungeon-of-rickedness

Similar to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142154/48249), how long is [Dungeons & Dragons vs. Rick & Morty](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/dungeons-dragons-vs-rick-and-morty)? Considerations:

- Game will be played in person.
- I will aim to have 5 players, not counting the DM.
- If I DM, I will push players to use the included characters rather than creating new ones.
- I expect to have two new players, and three that have played before. Of those three, one has DMed before.
- My goal in asking this question is to find a 5e campaign or module that can be finished in 1-4 sessions (I anticipate each session will run 4 or maybe 5 hours).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## This will finish in 3-4 sessions

I haven't completed it yet, but I ran through about 1/3 of the rooms (maybe a bit more) in our first 4 hour session. There is nothing in the module to assume the unvisited rooms will take longer, so I'd say my estimate is accurate and this fits within your goals.

I only played with 4 players, so if you've got a 5th, it'll slow it down a bit, but not enough to alter it beyond the 3-4 session.

### Game Notes

It's a ton of fun! I'd recommend playing it with the attitude of a Rick and Morty show and be open and accepting to the silliness of character death and recovery.

Comment: Happy to chat about it in [chat] if you'd like :)